# Is it bad practice to declare the AppDelegate class as 'final' in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

Right now, I'm trying to use a class from Git called Insomnia to prevent the device from locking while it is charging. The [project](https://github.com/ochococo/Insomnia) is here if you're curious. For the example code, it has me doing this:

```
final class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
      private let insomnia = Insomnia(mode: .whenCharging)
      //app delegate code
 }
```

As you can see, it has you declare the `AppDelegate` as `final` so that the `insomnia` variable isn't deallocated, which would stop it from working. However, I wasn't sure, is this bad practice to declare my `AppDelegate` as `final`? Or will this cause issues for my app? If it is bad practice, is there a better way of making sure `insomnia` isn't deallocated?

Comment: So is it not necessary to declare it as `final` then?

Comment: Looking at the project, it never claims that using `final` is there to prevent the `insomnia` variable from being deallocated. That appears to be your own conclusion, correct?

Comment: It's not bad practice...it's just kind of pointless. You can only have one instance active, and it's alive for the entire life cycle of your application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say:

> As you can see, it has you declare the `AppDelegate` as `final` so that the `insomnia` variable isn't deallocated ...

That’s not what `final` does. It merely says that the class cannot be subclassed (which is not likely to ever be relevant in the case of an app delegate). The `final` keyword also permits some optimizations (where if you had code calling any of these methods, it could use static dispatch instead of dynamic dispatch) that are unlikely to have any observable effect in this scenario.

Bottom line, you do not have to use `final` in this context.

"Best practice" would be to use `final` where you need to, namely where the class really cannot or should not be subclassed or where you really need the performance difference that static dispatch offers.

---

In answer to your question whether this is an acceptable place to declare `insomnia`, yes it is (but no `final` needed). The `AppDelegate` is not released while the app is running and it's where we generally put "app lifecycle" related code.